# lchoose function in R

Tags: r, radix, binomial-coefficients

My understanding of lchoose function in R is simply lchoose(a,b) = log(choose(a,b)).
However, I found that:

```
 temp <- 7.9999993
 k <- 8
 choose(temp,k)
 [1] 0
 lchoose(temp,k)
 [1] 0
 log(choose(temp,k))
 [1] -Inf
```

So lchoose is not log of the choose function output.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the discrete case (i.e discrete `n`), `choose(n,k)` computes the number of distinct k-element subsets from a set of `n` elements, so if `k > n`, then you are counting subsets of a set which have more elements that the corresponding set. Since there are no such subsets, then the answer is zero.

In general, for an `n` which is a real number, the function can still be computed, but however, the function still has to have the same meaning over discrete values, so for `k>n` the function has a value of zero. If you look at the definition of the binomial function with real `n` ([see here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Binomial_Coefficient/Real_Numbers)) you'll see that the answer will be zero, but I tried to explain it, hopefully, in an intuitive manner.

Comment: That's not what `?lchoose` says.

Comment: @BondedDust what do you mean?

Comment: The help page says it's defined for n being any real number and k being integer.

Comment: @BondedDust I see, they have used the generalized form. Sorry about that, give me one second, and I will fix it.

Comment: @BondedDust I just did modification.